# W10 IE 14(Edge) detectizr navigator.plugins error: permission denied

Tags: javascript, windows, microsoft-edge, browserstack

My web app is failing when I test it in BrowserStack, it breaks in the `detectizr.js` file, where `navigator.plugins` is being accessed. When I look at the `navigator` object via dev tools, I can see that for `plugins` there is a message saying **permission denied** and want to confirm if this is why my web app breaks in IE Edge and no other web browser. Has anyone encountered this issue? I am wondering if perhaps it's only an IE14 Edge setting that needs to be changed.

Comment: FYI - I contacted BrowserStack, since I think this is something they are restricting somehow. I'll post any useful information. However, if anyone knows how to disable access to plugins in IE, that'd be great to learn, so I can try to replicate this locally.

Comment: Update: BrowserStack was able to replicate the issue and are looking into it. It is fair to say this issue is only observed on BrowserStack with the specifications mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this same issue in IE Edge on BrowserStack when accessing `navigator.plugins`.  I am using socket.io-client.js which uses this check to see if Flash is enabled.  I don't see this issue on my actual Windows computers, so I believe you are on the right track that it is something specific to BrowserStack.

sorry - i wanted to comment not answer, but i don't have a good enough reputation to comment yet.  guess i'm not allowed to be helpful yet :(

Comment: Thanks. Did you edit introduce a workaround for BrowserStack? I don't think we should have to. Anyways, hang in there, you'll build up rep soon enough.

Comment: No i haven't found a solution yet, just not testing Edge on BrowserStack for now :(